# Gremlin with Neptune: filter edges using math result with previous edge value

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have the following graph:

[image]

And I want to solve the following traversal:

1. Start at node "abc-01-05"
2. Go to main "ip" node (id: abc)
3. Traverse out edges from ip node, where the date "at_millis" is less than the edge traversed in step 2 + 1 day
4. The result should be the nodes: abc-01-05 and abc-02-05

The best query I could make was based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68514385/gremlin-how-can-i-use-math-to-filter-traversal-results), but doesn't work:

```
g.V('abc-01-05')
    .outE('related_to').as_('saved_edge')
    .inV()
    .inE('related_to')
    .where(
        P.lte('saved_edge')
    )
    .by('at_millis')
    .by(__.math('saved_edge + 86400001').by('at_millis'))
    .toList()
```

This returns this error:

```
GremlinServerError: 500: {"requestId":"3aaaca37-75eb-4650-b111-130c6e65b040","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"Exception processing a script on request [RequestMessage{, requestId=3aaaca37-75eb-4650-b111-130c6e65b040, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(abc-01-05), outE(related_to), as(saved_edge), inV(), inE(related_to), where(lte(saved_edge)), by(at_millis), by([[], [math(saved_edge + 86400001), by(at_millis)]])]], aliases={g=g}}}]."}
```

Any help would be really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding another answer just to point out that the error you were seeing with your original query was because the `by` steps need to be reversed. The second `by` modulator is applied to the label within the `where` step. The first `by` modulator defines what it will be compared to. Also, to get the test to work, the value being tested needs a minor tweak. Here is a working version of the original query.

```java
g.V('abc-01-05')
    .outE('related_to').as('saved_edge')
    .inV()
    .inE('related_to').as('related')
    .where(P.lte('related'))
      .by(__.math('saved_edge + 86400000').by('at_millis'))
      .by('at_millis')
```

Comment: This solves my issue in a simpler way so I'm changing this to the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this :

```
g.V('abc-01-05').
  outE('related_to').as('saved_edges').
  values('at_millis').as('a1').
  math('a1 + 86400001').as('saved_edges_millis_plus_1_day').
  select('saved_edges').
  inV().
  inE('related_to').as('intermediate_edges').
  values('at_millis').
  where(P.lt('saved_edges_millis_plus_1_day')).
  select('intermediate_edges')
```

Comment: This returns the values correctly filtered, but I need the actual edges that have the property `at_millis` with that condition, not the values.

Comment: edited the answer to result edges.